# Hide quick launch sections on a specifc page using content editor

Tags: 2010, css, content-editor-web-part, quick-launch

I have a SharePoint (2010) list page. I have already found a useful piece of code that works in content editor to hide the quick launch bar:

```
<style type="text/css">           
   body #s4-leftpanel { display: none; }             
   .s4-ca { margin-left: 0px; }            
</style>​​
```

This works brilliantly.

However I am also using metadata navigation filtering on my list and when I hide the quick launch bar the meta data box also disappears with it.

Is there a way to use the content editor HTML code to hide the following sections:

1. Surveys
2. Sites
3. Libraries
4. Lists
5. Discussions
6. Site contents

(I am not so fussed about recycle bin and all site content).

This would then leave me with the bar containing just the filters section.

**Note**: I have seen elsewhere that you can manage this at the site level however I want the quick launch to remain unaffected for all other pages.

Answer (score 0):

Is this in general or just on this specific page?  The reason why I ask is that you could go through developer options (F12)  on the page and inspect the element.  If you are familiar with CSS, you can specifically call out what you want to hide.